# Is there a secure way to set up a mysql root password?

Tags: mysql, security

In [this how-to geek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/mysql/set-the-mysql-root-password/), the author talked about using

```
mysqladmin -u root -h host_name password “newpassword”
```

To set a new password. A person replied that that may leave the password in the shell's history file, and suggested using

```
mysql -u root mysql
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD(’newpasswordgoeshere’);
```

but another person said that it'd leave the password in the .mysql_history file.

Security isn't an issue for me (no-one else should have access to my computer), but is there a better alternative?

Comment: Also remember to check that no-one is looking over your shoulder when you type the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off MySQL history by setting

```
export MYSQL_HISTFILE=/dev/null
```

in your shell before starting mysql.

MySQL [environment vars](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/environment-variables.html) reference.

According to wikipedia the windows equivalent of [`/dev/null`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null) is `\Device\Null` or `NUL`.

Answer (score 7):

[As of MySQL 5.5.3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html#command_mysqladmin_password), the simplest way is with `mysqladmin`:

```
$ mysqladmin -p -u root password
Enter password:                     # ← current root password
New password:                       # ← new root password
Confirm new password:               # ← again
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use one of the options and delete the relevant history file.

Comment: Presumably the mysql history one, as that'd have less history at that point.

Answer (score 0):

`$ mysqladmin -p -u root password` seems to be the best way.